# How to get the redirect url from the redirect functions in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am using different redirection  functions in my code, like

```
return $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('profile/linto/', array('prependBase' => false));

return $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute($session->params, $session->route, $session->reset);

return $this->_redirect($uri, array('prependBase' => false));
```

All these situations , proper redirection is taking place.

But what i need is that , instead of redirecting, i need to get the redirect url that generates by these functions.

Any one have  idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL helper:

```
url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode)
```

eg.

```
$this->view->url($session->params, $session->route, $session->reset)
```

Check also [baseUrl() Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl):

eg.

```
$url = $this->view->baseUrl().'profile/linto/';
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion if for ZF2

From Controller you can redirect by:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('route', array('action' => 'your-action-name'));
```

From view file you have to use url helper

```
$this->url('route', array('action' => 'your-action-name'));
```